# prove integration formula relating to derivatives

Tags: integration, derivatives

[image]

Could any one help me solve this problem ? it is from Apostol's calculus volume 1

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you applied the fundamental theorem of calculus to $f$ to try to compute $f'$? What did you get?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$f(x)=\frac12 \int_0^x(x-t)^2g(t)dt=\frac12 \int_0^x(x^2-2tx+t^2)dt\\=\frac12 \int_0^x x^2g(t)dt+\frac12\int_0^x(-2tx)g(t)dt+\frac12\int_0^x t^2g(t)dt\\=\frac{x^2}{2} \int_0^x g(t)dt-x\int_0^xtg(t)dt+\frac12\int_0^x t^2g(t)dt.$$

Now, because of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, it is

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x g(t)dt=g(x), \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x tg(t)dt=xg(x),\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x t^2g(t)dt=x^2g(x).$$

Then apply the chain rule to get the derivative of $f.$

Comment: got it ,thank you very much